# Javascript member function declaration

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following object 'obj'. I tried to debug it and  seems like both functions are members 'render' and 'sort'. Is there any difference between these two types of declaration?

```
var obj = {
    render:function(){

    },
    sort(){

    }
}
```

Comment: `sort` is not function of `obj`. *Syntax Error*

Comment: That is not valid syntax for the `sort` method; it should follow the pattern by `render` as well.

Comment: In Chrome console I  don't get any Syntax Errors

Comment: did you call sort method ?

Comment: yes i did!  and was surprised myself to see it working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using new [object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6) introduced in ES6. It's perfectly valid, but won't work in older browsers and some current ones. If new Javascript features are of interest, you might consider looking into an ES6 [transpiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) such as [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) or [babel](https://babeljs.io/) so that you get cross-browser support.

Answer (score 1):

The first is an anonymous function expression. The second is a named function declaration. It is unusual to see named functions declared on object properties like this, because it's actually new ES6 syntax and won't work in many current browsers. For this reason it is not recommended that the second syntax be used for another year or two at least! It's nice though, isn't it?